# Can we use a VM in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a Neo4j VM as a database in Azure and I also use it to call Neo4j algorithms.

Is it possible to use this VM in Azure DevOps ? I searched on the Azure documentation and I found nothing.

I don't know if I can use a VM in Azure DevOps.

Comment: What do you want to do with the VM?

Comment: I would like to use it in a Pipeline in order to automate all my project. 
    I would like to have these steps:
1) Web scraping articles (python code)
2) Clean the data (python code)
3) Insert the data into Neo4j VM
4) Use Neo4j algorithms (graph data science library) with the Neo4j VM

Comment: So do you want to run an Azure DevOps pipeline in your VM?

Comment: I would like to use the VM in steps 3 and 4 of the pipeline, but I don't know if it is technically possible. I have the project in my laptop and I searched to automate everything in Azure.

Comment: You can install an azure pipelines agent in the vm, see the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install

Comment: Did you succeed to install the agent?

Comment: Hello @ShaykiAbramczyk, not yet. I'm learning how to do the pipeline in Azure DevOps. Actually I don't know how to install the agent.

Comment: @LJRB Shayki provided the link describing how to install the self-hosted agent in the comment above.

Comment: Hello I didn't succeed in doing it. I don't understand the link. I started a pipeline in Azure DevOps, I did first steps (cleaning data etc) and not the last steps : Insert the data into Neo4j VM 4) Use Neo4j algorithms (graph data science library) with the Neo4j VM).